# How can I gain a full access to files?

Tags: windows-xp, file-permissions

Due to the extent system errors on my notebook, I decided to only reformat the drive of the Windows. Unfortunately, after reformatting from Windows XP to Windows 7 ultimate, I can't access now the other unformatted drives.

Then I discovered converting the HDD to an external HDD, I can see now the files. Yet, those files neither be copied nor opened and always returning a request for a user to access the folder (`S-??-...`, something like this).

With the said details above, how can I gain a full access on those said files?

Answer (score 4):

Take ownsership of the files:

> 1. Right-click the file that you want to take ownership of, and then click Properties.
> 2. Click the Security tab, and then click OK on the Security message (if one appears).
> 3. Click Advanced, and then click the Owner tab.
> 4. In the Name list, click Administrator, or click the Administrators group, and then click OK.
>
> The administrator or the administrators group now owns the file.
>
> — http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421

Comment: I've tried following the steps stated here on the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421. Yet, it seemed not to work.

Comment: You are using the GUI or ICACLS?

Comment: If your saying about the GUI of windows, yes. I'm unfamiliar with icacls.exe.